# Feature detect if user gesture is needed

Tags: javascript, html5-video, modernizr, feature-detection

is there a way to detect if calling `play()` on a video element is allowed without a user gesture?
On Android Chrome this warning is given:

`Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

So on Chrome Android a user gesture is required to start the playback of a video, while it isn't on desktop Chrome. 
Is there a way to  detect which behavior I will get?

I want to have slightly different behavior in my app depending on if calling play programatically is allowed or not.

I have tried to use `Modernizr.videoautoplay`, but that checks if the `autoplay` property on the element, which is not the same thing. This gives false negatives for IE11 and Edge.

Edit: added [an example](http://ea7e83c432c066554d3ef3e6580aa1af9bd594a1.googledrive.com/host/0BwqnHXhKkJ7mfjF5clFzSUFSY3pjSzhxZlA0TnpIeEo2bHlaY2FZd3RhWDFHY1o2eXZsYXc/android_play_fail.html). The video will start playing automatically in Chrome desktop and IE11 or Edge (with 3s delay) on windows 8 or 10. For Chrome@Android a user interaction is needed (clicking the button) and the error message can be seen in the console.

Comment: can you post a code example that has that error?

Comment: Hi @Patrick  I have updated the question with a link to an example. Its a  bit complex (adding frames to the video bit by bit) but the issue can be seen

Comment: Hi @oskbor, did you get a fix for this?

Comment: Nope, did not find a way to detect that

Comment: I ended up just filtering var isMobile = false;
if ((/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) || (/Mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))) isMobile = true;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The play method returns a promise which can be used to catch the error.

Not all browsers follow [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-media-play) so you will have to check if what is returned is a promise first.

```
var autoPlayAllowed = true;
var promise = document.createElement("video").play();
if(promise instanceof Promise) {
    promise.catch(function(error) {
        // Check if it is the right error
        if(error.name == "NotAllowedError") {
            autoPlayAllowed = false;
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }).then(function() {
        if(autoPlayAllowed) {
            // Allowed
        } else {
            // Not allowed
        }
    });
} else {
    // Unknown if allowed
}
```

Comment: I think this needs to check whether `window.Promise` exists first, otherwise you'll get a reference error on browsers that don't support promises.

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome 70. Without a source set on the video element the promise hangs and doesn't resolve.